# Dry Calculus - Name the Song

Tags: mathematics, word, enigmatic-puzzle, music

[image: Dry Calculus]

Clues:
a=eru
5I 5I

[two contextual images]

Instructions: Name the Song
_ a _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the clues are hinting toward

> Sandstorm

> The tangent line in the first image suggests that we want to calculate the slope of the function $a = eru$. We can take the derivative of the function with respect to $e$ to get $da/de = ru$. Rearranging terms gives us $da = rude$, i.e., Darude, the artist of the song in question.

> I think the second clue is hinting toward the iconic 5 beat "du du du du du" that the song starts with, with the pause symbol next to the time signature referring to the musical rest between each set of 5 beats.

> <OP Edit - The 5 and I are in reference to Morse Code, which are dit-dit-dit-dit-dit and dit-dit, respectively. They are positioned on a percussion cleff (not a bass or treble) to signify that the rhythm is what is important>

As for the title

> Calculus is Latin for "small rock." So dry calculus can be taken to mean "sand" as well as the math we need to do for the first clue